# Does the inequality $ (a^{n-1} -b^{n-1})(a-b)\ge 0$ hold?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

Let $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$, $a, b\ge 0$ and $n\in (1, \infty)$.

Anyone could please help me to understand if the inequality
$$ (a^{n-1} -b^{n-1})(a-b)\ge 0$$
ie true?

I am trying "for attempts" and it seems true to me, but I would prefer to have a general proof. Anyone could please give me a hint?

Comment: Who is downvoting everyone? And why?

Comment: Is $n$ any integer $>1$, or it can be any real number $>1 ?$

Comment: @AdamRubinson, it can be any real number $>1$

Answer (score 3):

You have two cases.

Case 1: $a \ge b \ge 0$. Then $a^{n-1}\ge b^{n-1}$ because $n-1\ge 0$. Hence $a^{n-1}-b^{n-1}\ge 0$ and $a-b\ge 0$.

Case 2: $b>a \ge 0$. Then Then $a^{n-1}\le b^{n-1}$ because $n-1\ge 0$. Hence $a^{n-1}-b^{n-1}\le 0$ and $a-b\le 0$.

In both cases their product is $\ge 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Because $t\mapsto t^{n-1}$ is nondecreasing function.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The function $x\mapsto x^{n-1}$ is strictly increasing, so $a<b$ if and only if $a^{n-1}<b^{n-1}$. What does this say about the signs of $a-b$ and $a^{n-1}-b^{n-1}$?

Comment: Looks like a nitwit has downvoted all of the hint answers given. I'm going to upvote all of them to compensate. Please do the same, others.

Comment: MPW, upvoted everyone. About your answer: does it say that both $a-b<0$ and $a^{n-1}-b^{n-1}<0$, right? It should complete the proof.

Comment: @Physicsuser : Not quite, but it's close. The "if and only if" in the hint tells you that EITHER they are both $<0$, OR they are both $\geq 0$ (the negation of being $<0$). But by symmetry (interchanging $a$ and $b$), the hint tells you that EITHER they are both $>0$, OR they are both $\leq 0$. These then also imply that if they are not $<0$ or $>0$, then they must be both $\geq 0$ and $\leq 0$, i.e., they must both be $=0$. This takes care of all three cases. Following the logic through to the end is perhaps more work than it might seem, but you can't just say that it's true without proof.